# Footprint Style Stacked Bar Chart Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, trading

I want to create a chart like the one given below. how can I achieve something like that in matplotlib.
[image: footprint chart].

Comment: What did you try? How do you want to represent your input data? You can use `plt.bar` and set an explicit `bottom=`.

Comment: the input is price points. for example, one bar could start at 100 and end at 101. then in between I want to write a text